Trouble on dynamic updating of input field validation message in JavaScript
I'm working on a web form where the minimum and maximum values of one input field (size-ft2) are dynamically updated based on the value of another input field (size-ft1). Here's my HTML and JS code:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkprice = document.getElementById('checkprice_taurp');
    var sizeFt1 = document.getElementById('size-ft1');
    var sizeFt2 = document.getElementById('size-ft2');
    var form_taurp = document.getElementById('form-taurp');

    function updateFt2() {
        var minft1 = parseInt(sizeFt1.value);

        if (!isNaN(minft1)) {
            sizeFt2.min = minft1;

            switch (minft1) {
                case 2:
                    sizeFt2.max = 10;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sizeFt2.max = 10;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sizeFt2.max = 11;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sizeFt2.max = 12;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    sizeFt2.max = 15;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    sizeFt2.max = 10;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    sizeFt2.max = 16;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    sizeFt2.max = 12;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Error Returned to Default')
            }
        }
    }

    checkprice.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (form_taurp.reportValidity()) {
            updateFt2();
        }
    });
});
<form id="form-taurp">
    <label for="size-ft1">Size Ft1:</label>
    <input type="number" name="size-ft1" id="size-ft1" class="textinputs taurp-size" min="2" max="10" required>
    <br>
    <label for="size-ft2">Size Ft2:</label>
    <input type="number" name="size-ft2" id="size-ft2" class="textinputs taurp-size" required>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="checkprice_taurp">Check Price</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_taurp">Submit</button>
</form>



The issue I'm facing is that the validation message for size-ft2 does not update immediately when the value of size-ft1 changes. For example:
size-ft1: 2
size-ft2: 1
The validation message will be value should not be less than 2 which is great however when I change the size-ft1, say:
size-ft1: 3
size-ft2: 1
The validation message will be the same, it should say value should not be less than 3 which is not so great. But if I change the value of size-ft2, say:
size-ft1: 3
size-ft2: 2
Then it will show my desire validation message which is value should not be less than 3.
I’m guessing the value of size-ft2 is not being reset that’s why it’s acting this way, what i’ve tried to do is after calling the function updateFt() it will reset the minimum attribute value of size-ft2 to empty string like this:
   checkprice.addEventListener('click', function() {

        if (form_taurp.reportValidity()) {
        updateFt2();
        }
    
        if (form_taurp.reportValidity()) {
            sizeFt2.min = '';
        }


    });


But it’s just not working. Can you guys tell me what can be the issue here? Thank you!

Why is the call for updateFt2 wrapped into if (form_taurp.reportValidity())? size-ft1: 2 size-ft2: 1 - so your form is invalid already after that (once you clicked the check button.) Now you change it to size-ft1: 3 size-ft2: 1 - still invalid, but when you click your check button now, reportValidity will return false, meaning you are not even calling updateFt2 any more. So sizeFt2.min will not get updated to 3, but stay at the value it already had, 2.

Fixed it! Thanks, I overlooked that part. I called the updateFt2 outside of the condition and it works out fine.

You can update the max property on the input event of the first input element and then do something on the invalid event of the second input element.


const valuetovalue = new Map([
  [2, 10],
  [3, 10],
  [4, 11],
  [5, 12],
  [6, 15],
  [7, 10],
  [8, 16],
  [9, 12],
  [10, 12]
]);


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var form_taurp = document.getElementById('form-taurp');

  form_taurp['size-ft1'].addEventListener('input', e => {
    let form = e.target.form;
    if (e.target.validity.valid) {
      form['size-ft2'].max = valuetovalue.get(e.target.valueAsNumber);
    }
  });

  form_taurp['size-ft2'].addEventListener('invalid', e => {
    e.target.setCustomValidity(`A number, maximum ${e.target.max}`);
  }, true);
});
<form id="form-taurp">
  <label for="size-ft1">Size Ft1:</label>
  <input type="number" name="size-ft1" id="size-ft1" class="textinputs taurp-size" min="2" max="10" required>
  <br>
  <label for="size-ft2">Size Ft2:</label>
  <input type="number" name="size-ft2" id="size-ft2" class="textinputs taurp-size" min="0" required>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit_taurp">Submit</button>
</form>



